# Adding filter to GridView widget

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I am trying to add filter to [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html) widget included in `_form.php`. The grid is showing fine, even filter field is shown, but the filter is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<?php  
   $searchModel = New CitySearch(); ?>


    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

          //  'id',
            'city_name',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. The search model must actually be searched before attaching it to the GridView. Therefore, I just needed to add one line to get it to work:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

The entire code would like like that:

```
<?php  
   $searchModel = New CitySearch(); 
   $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
?>


<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

          //  'id',
            'city_name',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```